# When I try to run my program in Ubuntu bash I get this error : " /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found "

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, glibc

When I enter this into bash:"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64", my program starts working, but I have to enter this command into bash every time I start working with terminal, and it's quite bothering. Can anyone help me fix this permanently

@kfsone in libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py, inside this file :

```
import sys
import gdb
import os
import os.path

pythondir = '/usr/share/gcc-5.3.0/python'
libdir = '/usr/lib/../lib32'

# This file might be loaded when there is no current objfile.  This
# can happen if the user loads it manually.  In this case we don't
# update sys.path; instead we just hope the user managed to do that
# beforehand.
if gdb.current_objfile () is not None:
    # Update module path.  We want to find the relative path from libdir
    # to pythondir, and then we want to apply that relative path to the
    # directory holding the objfile with which this file is associated.
    # This preserves relocatability of the gcc tree.

    # Do a simple normalization that removes duplicate separators.
    pythondir = os.path.normpath (pythondir)
    libdir = os.path.normpath (libdir)

    prefix = os.path.commonprefix ([libdir, pythondir])
    # In some bizarre configuration we might have found a match in the
    # middle of a directory name.
    if prefix[-1] != '/':
        prefix = os.path.dirname (prefix) + '/'

    # Strip off the prefix.
    pythondir = pythondir[len (prefix):]
    libdir = libdir[len (prefix):]

    # Compute the ".."s needed to get from libdir to the prefix.
    dotdots = ('..' + os.sep) * len (libdir.split (os.sep))

    objfile = gdb.current_objfile ().filename
    dir_ = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (objfile), dotdots, pythondir)

    if not dir_ in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, dir_)

# Call a function as a plain import would not execute body of the included file
# on repeated reloads of this object file.
from libstdcxx.v6 import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers(gdb.current_objfile())
```

Comment: Put the command in your .bashrc?

Comment: @kfsone is there any other way? Because if I do this it will be equal to automatically performing this action every time I start bash.

Comment: Which directory is the offending library in?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is depending on a library that is not currently in the paths that your system checks for libraries. You can either add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your .bashrc so you don't have to manually set it yourselrf, or you can use `ldconfig` to add it system wide:

Option 1: edit /etc/ld.so.conf

Option 2: create a "locallibs.conf" file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d

in either case, you want two lines:

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib64
```

Then

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.


That's what I get when I enter this command into bash

Comment: how can I fix this mistake with an ELF file?

Comment: This is just a caution as ldconfig looks at libraries, it's ignoring that file because it's a python script not a library. I've no idea why it's there, but it should be human readable and you might be able to tell what it is/where it came from by viewing it.